# Add Materializecss Toast to SVG

Tags: svg, materialize

I like to integrate the Toasts from Materializecss to an SVG. I am able to import the `css` and `js` from `Materializecss`, but when I load the svg I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'touchAction' in null`

Example: http://www.idoodler.de/svgTest.svg

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for some time. I tried HTMLencoding the image, used base64-encoded image source, direct SVG inline image source. I got non of these to work, and that's mostly due to quotation marks. Plain old URLs proved simplest. (And the method I thought of last)

The solution proved very simple in the end:

```js
Materialize.toast('<img src=\"http://www.idoodler.de/svgTest.svg\" />', 5000);
```

The escaping is kind of ugly and error prone, though. First time I got this working but calling my own function instead of triggering Materialize.toast() directly:

```js
<script>
    function imageToast(imageUrl) {
        Materialize.toast('<img src="' + imageUrl + '" />', 5000);
    }
</script>

imageToast(http://www.idoodler.de/svgTest.svg);
```

By wrapping the image source in it's own function, we don't have to deal with all kinds of quotation marks anymore. This solution should also work with inline sourcing of the image using pure SVG or base64.

My guess is that you want this kind of dynamic, right? My suggestion is simply to generate the SVG you want, save it, then apply toast() to the URL directly.

Sources:
https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/

Here's a Codepen for you to try: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJrvpj

Good luck.